# Blocking any other application via Service

Tags: java, android

I'm creating a business application and must block any other application that the user tries to open. I am creating a service to it, but it's not working.

When run, it does not see the other applications when opened by the user.

I read some other posts here, but I could not solve.

Below is my service.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);

        startService(new Intent(this, clsServico.class));
    }
```

my class:

```
import android.app.ActivityManager;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.pm.ResolveInfo;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.util.Log;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;


public class clsServico extends Service {

    private static final long INTERVAL = TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(2); // em segundos
    private static final String TAG = clsServico.class.getSimpleName();
    private static final String APS_BG = "APS_BG";

    private Thread t = null;
    private Context ctx = null;
    private boolean running = false;

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        running =false;
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        running = true;
        ctx = this;

        // checa periodicamente se tem algum outro app na tela
        t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                do {
                    //checkAPS();

                    try {
                        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21)
                            listTasks();
                        else
                            listTasks_SDK21();

                    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {

                    }

                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(INTERVAL);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    }
                }while(running);
                stopSelf();
            }
        });

        t.start();
        return Service.START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    public void listTasks() throws PackageManager.NameNotFoundException {
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
            ActivityManager mgr = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
            List<ActivityManager.AppTask> tasks = mgr.getAppTasks();
            String packagename;
            String label;
            for (ActivityManager.AppTask task : tasks) {
                packagename = task.getTaskInfo().baseIntent.getComponent().getPackageName();
                label = getPackageManager().getApplicationLabel(getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo(packagename, PackageManager.GET_META_DATA)).toString();
                //Log.i(TAG, packagename + ":" + label);
            }
        }
    }

    public void listTasks_SDK21() throws PackageManager.NameNotFoundException {
        ActivityManager mgr = (ActivityManager)getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        List<ActivityManager.RecentTaskInfo> tasks = mgr.getRecentTasks(20, 0);
        String packagename;
        String label;
        for(ActivityManager.RecentTaskInfo task: tasks){
            packagename = task.baseIntent.getComponent().getPackageName();
            label = getPackageManager().getApplicationLabel(getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo(packagename, PackageManager.GET_META_DATA)).toString();
            Log.i(TAG,packagename + ":" + label);
        }
    }

    private void checkAPS() {
        /*
        if(apenasAPSAtivado(ctx)) {
            if(isInBackground()) {
                restoreApp(); // tras p frente
            }
        }
        */

        PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
        Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
        mainIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);

        ActivityManager mActivityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);


        List<ResolveInfo> appList = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(mainIntent, 0);
        Collections.sort(appList, new ResolveInfo.DisplayNameComparator(packageManager));
        List<PackageInfo> packs = packageManager.getInstalledPackages(0);
        for(int i=0; i < packs.size(); i++) {
            PackageInfo p = packs.get(i);
            ApplicationInfo a = p.applicationInfo;
            // skip system apps if they shall not be included
            if((a.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM) == 1) {
                continue;
            }
            //Log.i("packageName","" + p.packageName);
        }

        List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> RunningTask = mActivityManager.getRunningTasks(1);
        ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo run = RunningTask.get(0);
        Log.i("topActivity", run.topActivity.getClassName());




        Intent ints = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
        ints.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);

        List<ResolveInfo> intentlist = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(ints, PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);

        List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> processes = mActivityManager.getRunningTasks(Integer.MAX_VALUE);

        String pName = "";

        if (processes != null)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < processes.size(); i++) {
                String packageName = processes.get(i).topActivity.getPackageName();
                ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo temp = processes.get(i);
                try
                {
                    pName = (String) packageManager.getApplicationLabel(packageManager.getApplicationInfo(packageName, PackageManager.GET_META_DATA));
                }
                catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                //Log.i("RunningTaskInfo",pName + " : " + temp.id);
                /*
                if (savedapp.equals(pName)) {
                    // finish(pm.);
                    int code = intentlist.get(i).activityInfo.hashCode();
                    finishActivity(code);

                    mActivityManager.killBackgroundProcesses(packageName);
                    mActivityManager.restartPackage(packageName);
                    android.os.Process.killProcess(temp.id);
                    finishActivity(temp.id);
                }
                */

            }

        }


        List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> rt = mActivityManager.getRunningTasks(1000);
        for(int i = 0; i < rt.size(); i++){
            ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo ar = rt.get(i);
            String activityOnTop=ar.topActivity.getClassName();
            //Log.i("rt", activityOnTop);
        }
        //ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo ar = rt.get(0);
        //String activityOnTop=ar.topActivity.getClassName();
        //Log.i("activityOnTop", activityOnTop);


        //ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager)ctx.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> pids = mActivityManager.getRunningAppProcesses();
        for(int i = 0; i < pids.size(); i++)
        {
            ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo p = pids.get(i);
            if(!p.processName.equalsIgnoreCase("nog.aps3")){
                android.os.Process.killProcess(p.pid);
                try {
                    android.os.Process.killProcess(p.pid);
                    android.os.Process.sendSignal(p.pid, android.os.Process.SIGNAL_KILL);
                    mActivityManager.killBackgroundProcesses(p.processName);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    //Log.i("try", e.toString());
                }
            }

            //Log.i("info.processName", p.processName);
            //isInBackground();
        }

    }

    private boolean isInBackground() {
        ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);

        List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> taskInfo = am.getRunningTasks(1);
        ComponentName componentInfo = taskInfo.get(0).topActivity;
        //Log.i("getPackageName", ctx.getApplicationContext().getPackageName() +" =? "+ componentInfo.getPackageName());

        return (!ctx.getApplicationContext().getPackageName().equals(componentInfo.getPackageName()));
    }

    private void restoreApp() {
        //restore other class
    }

    public boolean apenasAPSAtivado(final Context context) {
        SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        return sp.getBoolean(APS_BG, false);
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me with this, pls?

Comment: Quick question : Why would you want to create such an exclusive application ?

Comment: "must block any other application that the user tries to open" -- that is not possible in general, for obvious privacy and security reasons. You are welcome to look into the device owner APIs to see what possibilities are there. "it does not see the other applications when opened by the user" -- that is not terribly surprising. [`getRecentTasks()` has not worked since Android 5.0](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#getRecentTasks(int,%20int)), and `getAppTasks()` would appear to be unrelated to what you are trying to do.

Comment: The application is only for corporate use employee forthe company, will be a working tool, so the rest should not be used.
My client showed an application that does this ... that's the problem!